# Windows Application accesing files on Webserver

Tags: c#, winforms, mime-types, file-extension, windows

I'm trying to make a Game Launcher, that looks through all of the game files located on my Webserver on the internet, and updates the local files, depending if the "If modified since" value has changed.

Im using C# with Windows application, and my code does works to access some files, but not all. Files like .DLL and files without and extension (.FILE) doesn't get allowed access, which I don't understand.

I've tried to add this MIME type to my Web.config, which solves the access of some files, but not all of them.

```
<mimeMap fileExtension="*" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
```

Basicly, I need a way where I can access any file on my webserver, through HttpWebRequest/Response in a C# Windows Application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, probably you need to add the corresponding MIME-types in the IIS Manager as well.

Comment: Thats not an option for me, since all the files, and the Web.config is running on a Webserver, run by the Webhosting company "Unoeuro". So I need a way to do it, by the Web.config I guess.